# Annotating react children with props for the sake of the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it considered bad practice to annotate the children of a react component with properties solely to provide information to said component? For example suppose I have a navigation component which requires a name for each child component.

```
<Nav>
<Child name="child1"/>
<Child name="child2"/>
</Nav>
```

Here the 'name' property is only used by Nav. The only other way I can think of accomplishing this is by passing in an array of names as a property to nav where each element contains the name of the corresponding child index, but this is fragile and less declarative. Alternatively I could provide a map of names to child elements to nav instead of relying on props.children but this seems ugly. Doing things this way feels natural but also unreactish, am I breaking some best practice or idiom? If so, how should I implement something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by ugly? The component which only takes props is called stateless component, which is completely standard in React

Comment: `
 <Nav elMap={{
 "child1": <Child />
 "child2": <Child />
 }}/>
`

is uglier and less intuitive than

`
 <Nav>
  <Child name="child1"/>
  <Child name="child2"/>
 </Nav>
`

in my opinion. The latter resembles standard HTML layout and
indicates how the child elements will be used. The former
is less declarative and requires the person reading the 
code to read Nav to fully understand how elMap is used.
My question is mainly whether or not the latter is 
acceptable.

Comment: You could implement it, like this `const children = ['child1', 'child2']; const renderList = children.map(child=><Child key={child} name={child} />)`, since there is no another parameter, and they are the same component.

Comment: Hermes, are you saying the `Nav` component uses the name property on each child, and the `Child` component doesn't need the name prop?

Comment: @brentatkins that is correct. This would be the natural way to accomplish it without a framework since the markup is properly declarative (The name is associated with the child rather than the nav element), however I suspect it may be frowned upon in React (if it is, I would like clarification about what the rationale is).

Comment: @FisNaN the above was just an example to illustrate the broader question. The contents of Nav do not need to have the uniformity in the example above (they may be arbitrary elements).

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle, I only add props to components that require them. So in your case, I would only add the `name` prop if the `Child` component required it. It would be quite confusing to see a prop on a component in the parent element, yet not find the child component using it.

An alternative to your approach would be to create a wrapping child component. You could create a `NavItem` wrapper that is used as such:

```
<Nav>
  <NavItem name="child1">
    <Child />
  </NavChild>
  <NavItem name="child2">
    <Child />
  </NavChild>
</Nav>
```

The NavItem doesn't need to render any mark up, instead it could just render the children.

```
const NavItem = (props) => props.children;
```

This way, you parent Nav component gets a child with the props it needs, and you don't dirty the Child components with props it doesn't expect.

Comment: I don't see how this is any cleaner than simply adding a custom property directly to the child. It doesn't solve the problem you mention (it only adds more markup) since the Nav component will still need to inspect the 'name' property of the newly created NavItem component which is a violation of an identical kind in the sense that 'name' is not directly used by NavItem but by Nav.